# Upload file (image) by .put() method to firebase-storage get unexpected result

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, frontend, firebase-storage

I'm newbie of Firebase, specially Firebase-storage. I'm trying follow  [Firebase-storage upload files docs][1].

When try to upload file (i try a .jpg image file) from URL (get URL from <input tag and method URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])) use .put() method, Firebase-storage was updated, but have a problem: size of this image just 9 Bytes (B), can't preview in Storage and can't render to <img tag of browser. I rendered this .jpg image files with .getDownloadURL() method as [Firebase-storage download files docs][2]. This is 2 image of result [Upload with .put() method - result in Storage conslole][3] and [Upload with .put() method - result in browser][4]

In the other hand, when i upload the same files above (.jpg image file) manually - use Upload File button in Storage console, size of this file in Storage console is 79.98 Kilobytes (KB), i can preview in Storage console and can render to <img tag with [.getDownloadURL()][2] method too. This is 2 image of result: [Upload manually with Upload File button - result in Storage conslole][5]  and [Upload manually with Upload File button - result in browser][6]

And now is code of .put() method in ProcessImage.js file (i think problem was produced in this file)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { storage } from "./firebaseConfig";
import "firebase/storage";

function ProcessImage() {
  const [imgURL, setImgURL] = useState("");
  
  // Create a storage reference from our storage service
  var storageRef = storage.ref();

  // Create a reference to feeds1_avata_icon.jpg
  var flagRef = storageRef.child("feeds1_avata_icon.jpg");

// After choose image, immediately put this image to Firebase-storage
  function loadImg(event) {
    // get file from input
    var file = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

    // put file to storage
    flagRef
      .put(file, {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
      })
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log("Uploaded a blob or file!");
      });
  }

// if click button, render image from Firebase-storage to <img tag
  function handleDownload() {
    flagRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      setImgURL(url);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" id="uploadFile" onChange={(e) => loadImg(e)} />
      <img src={imgURL} alt="" id="image" />
      <input type="button" value="Button" onClick={handleDownload} name="" />
    </div>
  );
}
export default ProcessImage;
```

Next is my firebaseConfig.js file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore"; 
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBU8gkh5H0NwfTTbZ-VQNaF8lAcdkyV31Y",
  authDomain: "facebook-clone-f4938.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "facebook-clone-f4938",
  storageBucket: "facebook-clone-f4938.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "584659342846",
  appId: "1:584659342846:web:b1b19535364ca4f1e6dcaf",
  measurementId: "G-FQH967H0YJ",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();
const providers = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
var storage = firebaseApp.storage()
export { auth, providers, storage };
export default db;
```

Some information about version in package.json:

```
"name": "facebook-clone-2.0",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@firebase/storage": "^0.9.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "antd": "^4.19.5",
    "firebase": "^8.10.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-with-firebase-auth": "^1.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

This problem i get when run ReactJs app in localhost. Now i'm stuck i got no idea. Thanks for all help!
[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files?hl=en&authuser=0
[2]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?hl=en&authuser=0
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cCU6.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDOXa.jpg
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJDve.jpg
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKJXv.jpg

Comment: You can directly upload the file using `flagRef.put(event.target.files[0])` instead of creating an object URL. Can you try it that way? Also it's best to check if `event.target.files[0]` is defined using an if statement before uploading

Comment: @Dharmaraj wow it's work, thanks you so much. I'm so stupid right now :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object directly into [`put()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.storage.Reference#put) that takes a blob or ArrayBuffer as first parameter. There's no need to create an object URL for the same.

```
flagRef.put(event.target.files[0])
```

You should also check if the user has actually selected a file or not. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
function loadImg(event) {
  // get file from input
  const file = event.target.files[0];

  if (file) {
    // put file to storage
    flagRef
      .put(file, {
        contentType: "image/jpeg",
      })
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log("Uploaded a blob or file!");
      });
  } else {
    alert("Please select a file")
  }
}
```